# Xcode frameworks are red in color though it is added to the project. Xcode 12.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios14, xcode12

I'm new to iOS Development.

I have an iOS project which was working fine in xcode 12.1 and when I update it to 12.2, the below frameworks are start showing red in color.
[image]

I have tried remove and adding these frameworks in the project file.

[image]

Comment: The only times I've seen this is with accidentally *moving* (instead of *copying*) files of any sort from one project to another. I've never - never! - seen this with any Core* frameworks. My only thought? What If you create a blank project and try using these? Okay - one more thought. Does your current project build despite missing these frameworks? Truth is, with this latter thought, I've never needed to add these frameworks to my projects - either `Foundation` or anymore, `UIKit` already has them.

Comment: Did you  try to build and run the project as is? If so, does it throw any build issues?